# Script Mediator Error in WSO2Carbon 4.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2carbon 4.2.0 and installed wso2esb 4.8.1 into it.. While creating a proxy service using script mediator i am getting an error

Below is my proxy service Configuration

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JsonToXMLProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="Proxy-Authorization"
                   expression="fn:concat('Basic', base64Encode('INDIA\uname:pwd'))"
                   scope="transport"/>
         <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <script language="js">var cel= mc.getPayloadJSON().CelsiusToFahrenheit.Celsius.toString();
             mc.setPayloadXML(&lt;CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"&gt;
             &lt;Celsius&gt;{cel}&lt;/Celsius&gt;           
             &lt;/CelsiusToFahrenheit&gt;);</script>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <header name="Action"
                 value="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit"/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"
                  format="soap11"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>`
```

and i am getting the following error while trying to save this proxy (Source View)

```
`[2014-03-21 10:30:12,621] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ui.client.ProxyServiceAdminClient} -  com/sun/phobos/script/javascript/RhinoScriptEngineFactory
org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.stub.ProxyServiceAdminProxyAdminException: com/sun/phobos/script/javascript/RhinoScriptEngineFactory
        at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ui.client.ProxyServiceAdminClient.addProxy(ProxyServiceAdminClient.java:105)
        at org.apache.jsp.proxyservices.submit_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.proxyservices.submit_jsp:107)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)`
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue...

Thanks alot in Advance...

Comment: Does this work on a standalone ESB 4.8.1 product?

Comment: @Isuru Yes...I tried this same proxy service on wso2esb 4.8.1 ,it's working...But it's not working here??? Can you help me on this...I want to do like this,,,need to install different features on wso2carbon..